# The color is displayed incorrectly

Tags: android

I have been scratching my head about this one. I have tried setting a theme with red colors. However, when i test my app on my Galaxy 3 the red is much brighter. Instead of a nice and subtle red, it's bright and screaming. Can anyone help me? I guess colors differ between phone models but this has gone from nice to ugly.

[Illustration of red colors](http://oi57.tinypic.com/15qep20.jpg)

1 is what i wanted to achieve, 2 is closer to what i got.

#### themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#f44336</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#d32f2f</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#ff5252</item>

        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: have you checked the device screen brightness to be equal on both tested devices? there could be many factors to why the same color definition might look different on different screens including screen brigthness/color saturation etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's simply no way to get the red shade you like to appear universally on different devices. To start with, OLED screens versus LCD screens are going to draw that red shade using different primaries. And the differences only start there: Users will have different display preferences in effect for brightness, saturation, etc. The workaround on professional displays is to offer calibration routines that involve probes, LUTs, etc. Those aren't available to you in this case, alas. I think you'll have to learn to live with an approximation of your theme colors.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem with Amoled display, because colors on Amoled displays are brighter.
Try to down saturation level, e.g. #ff5252 equal to HSL 0-240-159, may be 0-180-159 (#ea6868) will better.

Answer (score 0):

As you told each manufacturer has its own custom display settings, and it shows colors different from other displays. And also don't forget that each display has its own custom settings it might be brighter or darker depends on user interest. So you can not have similar colors in all screens.
I suggest you to pick the hex color of each screen to be sure that colors are shown correctly.